# execute non query not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add new values to database but executenonquery is not working. I have tested and realized that just after executing non query, the system stops working. In short, it does not fire. There is no error returned. Here is the code:

```
else
{
    double amounts = Convert.ToDouble(InstallmentPaidBox.Text);
    string date = period.Text;
    SqlCommand a = new SqlCommand("Select top 1* from Minimum_Amount order by Period desc", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader sq = a.ExecuteReader();

    while (sq.Read())
    {
        string date2 = sq["Period"].ToString();
        double amount = Convert.ToDouble(sq["Amount"]);
        double areas = amount - (Convert.ToDouble(InstallmentPaidBox.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(BalanceBroughtTextBox.Text));
        double forwarded = Convert.ToDouble(BalanceBroughtTextBox.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(InstallmentPaidBox.Text);
        double balance = areas;
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Cash_Position(Member_No,Welfare_Amount, BFWD,Amount,Installment_Paid,Loan_Repayment,Principal_Paid,Loan_Balance,Interest_Paid,Interest_Due,Penalty_Paid,Penalty_Due,Installment_Arrears,CFWD,Balance_Due,Period,Date_Prepared,Prepared_By) values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n,@o,@x,@p,@q)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = MemberNumberTextBox.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.Money).Value = WelfareAmount.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@c", SqlDbType.Money).Value = BalanceBroughtTextBox.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@d", SqlDbType.Money).Value = amounts;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@e", SqlDbType.Money).Value = InstallmentPaidBox.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@f", SqlDbType.Money).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@g", SqlDbType.Money).Value = PrincipalPaid.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@h", SqlDbType.Money).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@i", SqlDbType.Money).Value = InterestPaid.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@j", SqlDbType.Money).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@k", SqlDbType.Money).Value = PenaltyPaid.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@l", SqlDbType.Money).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@m", SqlDbType.Money).Value = areas;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.Money).Value = forwarded;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@o", SqlDbType.Money).Value = balance;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@x", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = period.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateOf.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@q", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = prepared.Text;

        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rows > 0)
        {
            string script = "<script>alert('Data Successfully Added')</script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Added", script);
        }
        else
        {
            string script = "<script>alert('Error Adding Data')</script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Error", script);
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this from a background thread? If so it is probably throwing an exception which is getting swallowed (since it's in the background thread).

Comment: you are interrupting the connection.

Comment: so, how can i ensure the connection is not interrupted

Comment: Are there any rows in the Minimum_Amount table?

Comment: yes, there are rows. it is only after the command execute non query that I recieve no response from the program

Comment: @OwalaWilson: I assume that you're misunderstanding the js-alert registered by `RegisterClientScriptBlock`. It is not executed immediately. Instead you'll see it when the page is rendered next time. So there is _no response_ until the page is shown at the client later(or never if you `Response.Redirect`).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot execute any commands on a connection which is associated with an open data reader. You have to close the reader or use another connection. Because your reader is used by the open reader exclusively.

---

By the way you should be catching an `System.InvalidOperationException` with detail,

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

[Here is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/08/20/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-closed-first-explained.aspx) what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a breakpoint near the while statement and do debugging on that. Or you can do a step-into inside the function. If there are no rows in the Minimum_Amount table ,the execution may not reach your code snippet inside the while loop.

Comment: i did that already and the execution does not reach break point after executenonquery

Comment: @OwalaWilson Try putting the breakpoint just after the ExecuteReader Line and then check the number of rows returned. Also try executing the select query (select top1 ...) directly on the database.